# "The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I'm creating an ASP.NET Core web application with Visual Studio 2022

I've installed:

- `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLServer`
- `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`

If I run this command in the Nuget package manager console:

```
PM> Scaffold-DbContext "Server=CENTRAL\XPRESA; DataBase=DBSalez;User Id=sa;Password=12345; Encrypt=False" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

I got this error:

> Scaffold-DbContext : Exception calling "Start" with "1" argument(s): "The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform."

My OS: Windows 11 (Version 22H2)

The exception refers the S.O

Now, if I run this command on an older PC (with Windows 10), it works.

I've deleted the environment variable `C:\Program Files\dotnet\` in `Path`, and deleted the content of this folder `C:\Users\Myuser\.nuget\packages`

I've reinstalled Entity Framework Core (I've tested even older versions rebuilding application), but the result stays the same.

Please, does anyone know how could I fix this issue?

Comment: I tested it should be working on both win10 and win11. Try adding `-force` in the command. Also, which package version you're using? I'm using 6.0.7 and it works.